# Nginx proxy_pass response URL editing

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

My Nginx is listening on port 4321 with config that looks something like this:

```
  location /delivery {
    proxy_pass http://frontend-app/;
  }
```

The requests reach the frontend-app just fine, however the frontend-app responds with URLs that are missing the /delivery part and so all the subsequent requests are not able to reach 4321:/delivery because the request URLs go straight to root instead 4321:/myjs.js and not 4321:/delivery/myjs.js

The frontend-app has its own nginx that responds with this.

```
   location / {
   gzip on;
   gzip_types      application/javascript;
   gzip_proxied    any;
   gzip_min_length 64;
   gzip_http_version 1.0;

   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
```

I tried adding in sub_filter directives and it kind of works but not completely.
Could somebody give advice on how to properly handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your `nginx.conf` (did not test):

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^/(myjs\.js)/\w+$"){
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name:4321/delivery/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Tried with this but unfortunately did not work for me. However this only covers the .js par right? If I understand correctly proxy_redirect should handle scenarios like this, but I have tried like this:
proxy_redirect / /delivery/; 
but that did not work either. I did try some other variations in proxy_redirect but also to no avail.

Comment: @XenAinars yes, only `myjs.js` as you asked in your question, I suppose, you need to `rewrite` , not `proxy_redirect`, also check your `access.log` and `error.log` (I would log only needed `location {}`)